# Cocos2D iPhone - fade out of sprite leaving debris

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I have created a sprite and inside that sprite I have a label like this.

```
CCLabelTTF *myLabel = [CCLabelTTF 
                        labelWithString:text
                        dimensions:CGSizeMake(mySpriteWidth*0.9, mySpriteHeight*0.9) 
                        alignment:UITextAlignmentCenter 
                        fontName:@"Helvetica Neue" fontSize:20.0f];

[myLabel setPosition: CGPointMake((mySpriteWidth/2.0f),(mySpriteHeight/2.0f))];
[mySprite addChild: myLabel];
```

as you see the label is a child of mySprite.

Then I fade out the sprite using this action

```
id fadeOut = [CCFadeOut actionWithDuration:0.4];
```

The sprite fades out correctly, but the label continues there, arrogantly looking at me...

is this a bug or I am missing something? Thanks

---

the code I use to do the fade is this:

```
    CCSequence *sequence =[CCSequence actions:
                            fadeIn,
                            [CCDelayTime actionWithDuration:2.5],
                            fadeOut,
                            nil];


    [mySprite runAction:sequence];
//    [myLabel runAction:sequence];
```

adding the action to the label, makes it vanish, but then the sprite stays on the screen... :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be removing the sprite after the fade is complete. when it is removed if you are not going to use it again. or toggle its visibility if you will.

I'm not 100% sure if fade out will echo to its inner views. it affects objects that inherit from CCRGBAProtocol

[CCFadeout reference](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/0.99.0/interface_c_c_fade_out.html)

this should get you around your problem at least. if u want the label to fade out also you can access the label using getChildByTag to give it a fade effect also.

But you will need to create a new fade effect, the way Actions are implemented in cocos is that 2 objects can run the same action, the latter will.

Comment: As far as I see, it should affect the label, as the label is a subobject inside the sprite... I did the fade effect to the label. Now the label goes and the sprite continues...

Comment: I updated my reply, btw, if u put the line where the label runs the action before the sprite, the label will stay.
u just need to make another identical action for the other object

Comment: sorry to hijack, but how do you access the sprite in the callback function? I can't get the reference to the sprite and thus cant hide it, please help